# Why is pyshortcuts not working? And why am I not seeing a shortcut icon?

Tags: python

I have installed pyshortcuts, and I'm trying to open a Tkinter app by clicking on a shortcut icon.

```
from pyshortcuts import make_shortcut
make_shortcut('app.py', name='name', icon='icon.png')
```

This code is not working: there is no shortcut icon, and I'm not getting any error messages in the terminal.

I was expecting to see a shortcut on my Desktop, but nothing is showing up. And as I said, there's also no error message.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What platform?  Almost all of the code in `pyshortcuts` is platform-specific, so without that information we have no idea where to start looking for a problem.

Comment: `make_shortcut(...)` also returns some details about the shortcut that was created. Can you share that?

Comment: There was nothing returned in the terminal.

Comment: I am using a computer that uses Intel, is that what kind of platform you were looking for?

Comment: The OS (Operating System), i.e. Windows, Linux or MacOS.  Note that the icon formats supported by: Windows is ".ico", Linux is ".png", MacOS is ".icns".